# How to eliminate references when switching activities? [Android]

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been really trying to figure out how to use memory management in my program. Another post said System.gc() is a bad practice, and it also doesn't seem to really do too much for me anyway.

Main question: after reading tons on memory management, I am constantly stumbling across "eliminate references" (because they cause memory leaks). What does that mean? How do I eliminate references to things? Also I use SharedPreferences to store variables between activities so would that contribute to memory leaks?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: I have seen a lot of tips and posts about what not to do, but I dont know if my code violates those rules.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a method `reset` where I empty all the values created, this way you clean all the data that has been stored!Inside this method you just call to every variable you think occupies space and empty them.

Comment: How do you "empty" like an integer or textview etc.?

Comment: you can do it by setting `a = null;`